# How can i back to the previous folder in a cloud app ? WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, directory, back

I'm doing a Cloud application. I have 2 VIews (RootView,FolderView)
I can navigate through multiple layers of folders (folder inside another folder).
I used the same view to display the content of each folder.Only the properties of my element binded to the view are changing  when the user click on a folder.

The problem I encountered is that im not able to back to the previous folder with the "back" button...Because the user doesn't navigate to a different view when he click on a folder...

When I click on the back button I come back to the root.(The rootView).

I tried to used the **Navigate()** function to reload the same view on the click on a folder but it seems that the **OnNavigatedTo** event is not called ...

What can I do to be able to back to the previous folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use this line of code to create a new instance of a view...Then I was able to navigate as I wanted with the back stack...

```cs
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/Views/BDocs/FolderView.xaml?id={0}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), UriKind.Relative));
```